# Set landscape image to uinavegationBar with iOS5

Tags: ios5, landscape-portrait

I am developing and iOS app with both positions, Landscape and Portrait.

Using iOS5,  I Would like to set a Background image to a custom UINavegationBar.

I used that:

```
if([self.navBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:)] ) {

    [self.navBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"TabBarContactsPort.png"]  forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [self.navBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"TabBarContactsLand.png"]  forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsLandscapePhone];
}
```

I write this code at the viewDiLoad method, and it works ok for Portrait but use the same image for Landscape mode.

Please, help me and thaaanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the background image conditionally as follow:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    [super willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];

  if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation)) {
        [self.navBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"TabBarContactsLand.png"]  forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsLandscapePhone];
    }
    else if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(toInterfaceOrientation)) {
        [self.navBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"TabBarContactsPort.png"]  forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: UIBarMetricsLandscapePhone not works. Your answer works if I always use the "forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault".